# swift - Add blur to UIView in order to "blur" the Controller below? Read before

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I know that this question could appears a duplicate, but please read before downvote!

I have this `ReachabilityViewController` with a UIView named `pickerView` in it, as you can see in this picture below

[image]

My desired result is this:

[image]

but I get this instead:

[image]

This is my class of the viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ReachabilityViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: pickerView outlets and actions
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var startEndLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

}


// MARK: - Table view data source
extension ReachabilityViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        self.view.addSubview(pickerView)
        pickerView.alpha = 0.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.pickerView.alpha = 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

how to get the effect I want? 
**I already set `pickerView` backgroundColor as clear.**

Comment: You may use Debug View Hierarchy (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html) to check what's that grey view.

Comment: it's a view that came with the uiBlurEffectView...don't know how it works

Comment: Step 1: Search for "Adding blur effect to background in swift". Step 2: Go through some of the results, and learn how to do that. Step 3: Use that knowledge to blur the background of the view holding your Picker View.

Comment: @DonMag that's exactly what I've done -.-
I opened this topic because I get this result even if I don't explain that, and asked for help.

Comment: @EliaCrocetta - ok, but you didn't show any of the code you wrote to *create* the blur effect. Pretty tough to say "here is where you went wrong" if you don't show where you are going to begin with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this is what I've done

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var pickerDataSource = ["White", "Red", "Green", "Blue"];
@IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.regular)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self
    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.pickerView)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerDataSource.count;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerDataSource[row]
}
```

}[image]

[image]